# jQuery UI Accordion create event isn't firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I need to run some code after my jQuery UI accordion initializes. According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#event-create), I should be able to define a create event that runs when an accordion is created. But it never fires, even though the accordion is very successfully created.

```
$('#accordion').accordion({ 
    create: function(event, ui) { alert('This never fires'); },
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 and UI 1.8.5. Any idea why this event may be not firing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that jQuery UI 1.8.5 does not support the create: event. So you have to be using at least 1.8.9 in order to use it.

I wish the jQuery UI documentation had some reference to what version these features were added to.

Comment: 100% agree - I also wish the jQuery UI documentation said what version features were added.